# Python and telethon module get error AuthKeyUnregisteredError

Tags: python, telethon

I made a bot that monitors 4 news channels, and when the necessary words come across in messages, it sends them to me on the social network in private messages. Everything works fine - on my computer. If I run this script on another PC: it completely kicks me out of all telegram accounts, from all devices, and in the console, this is the error:

```
Cannot get difference for channel 1600394546 since the account is not logged in: AuthKeyUnregisteredError
```

I can’t understand why on my PC where I did all this it works fine - but on another computer which is located in the same room, connected to the same router, the same time zone and time - it throws out and writes the following error
At the same time, on the main computer I close my script so that there is only one input for api_id and api_hash - but it still knocks out the account from all devices

I discovered an interesting point.
If you run a script on a remote computer via the console, all devices from this account are logged out.
And if I run it through the PyCharm program - everything is fine!
In both cases, I create a virtual environment for downloading packages.
Does anyone know what could be the difference between such launches?